# You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource PNPJS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pnp-js-core, ms-graph-client

We have an portal where an azure AD user will login and will be able to see the data from list on sharepoint.

Trying to achieve this using [PNPJS](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) and [Angular MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular)

For the development phase,executed all list operation successfully using
[sp-rest-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-rest-proxy) but when same angular project was built and uploaded in azure web app, it gives an error as `"{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}`"

Response Headers also have error as `X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.`
Now with SP setup variable

```
const SPHeaders: any = {
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
 };
 sp.setup({
  sp: {
  baseUrl: "SharePoint siteUrl",
  headers: SPHeaders
  }
 });
```

Note : User successfully logs in and I can active directory user info with the help of graph api.

I even tried passing token which I get after authentication in SP setup like below, but that gives an error as  **reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"**
Please forgive me on my ignorance as I am working for the first time on SharePoint stack. Please help me access the lists.

```
 sp.setup({
      sp: {
        baseUrl: environment.web,
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use MSAL with PnPjs, you need to do a few more steps:

1. Need to install the `PnPjs MSAL client` as below:

`npm install @pnp/msaljsclient --save`

2. After that, you can use it in your code as below:

```
import { MsalClientSetup  } from "@pnp/msaljsclient";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
```

3. Then in your app, you can initialize it as:

```
sp.setup({
    sp: {
        fetchClientFactory: MsalClientSetup({
            auth: {
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
                clientId: <your-client-id>,
                redirectUri: "https://<your-tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/test.aspx",
            },
        }, ["https://<your-tenant>.sharepoint.com/.default"]),
    },
});

const r = await sp.web();
```

Reference - [msaljsclient - MSAL Client for PnPjs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/authentication/msaljsclient/#calling-sharepoint-via-msal)